# RoR "undefined method `title'" when invoking the 'new' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and am following the Apress 'Beginning Rails 3' book.
I created an Articles controller and an Article model, scaffolded and migrated like instructed in the book.

My code is the same as in the source linked in the book:
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/ccjr/blog/chapter04.zip

The only difference is that in articles_controller.rb file, instead of xml I have json
For example, in my articles_controller.rb there's

```
format.json { render json: @articles }
```

And in "their's" there will be

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
```

Which makes me think there's a compatibility issue, or that I installed something wrong.

Anyway this is the full error that I get

```
undefined method `title' for #<Article id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Extracted source (around line #16):

```
13: 
14:   <div class="field">
15:     <%= f.label :title %><br />
16:     <%= f.text_field :title %>
17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :body %><br />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RoR - undefined method `title' for #<Product:0x596c148>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316320/ror-undefined-method-title-for-product0x596c148)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `title` attribute in your `Article` model. Are you sure that you're preparing all migrations? Try `rails console` command and then inside this console type `Article.column_names` and check them - is there `title` column? And also check files in db/migrations folder.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run your db:migrate?

The message is pretty clear; there's no "title" method/attribute yet.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see you have error in `format.json { render json: @articles }`. Try `format.json { render :json => @articles }`

Comment: Ruby 1.9 map syntax, and certainly not related to the error message :)